# Wired error in a function call

Tags: c, string, function, call

The following function is supposed to crypt a string of up to 10 chars.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void crypt(char*);

int main()
{
    //one random message of up to 10 chars and function call.
    char str[7] = "george";

    crypt(str);

    printf("%s",str);
}

//this function crypt's the initial string's message.
void crypt(char str[])
{
   int i=0;

   while ((i<=10)&&(str[i]!='\0'))
   {
      if (str[i]<=119) {str[i] = str[i] + 3;}
      else if (str[i]==120) {str[i]='a';}
      else if (str[i]==121) {str[i]='b';}
      else {str[i]='c';}
      i++;
   }
}
```

}

Instead, DevC++ gives me this error:

```
***In function 'int main':
[Error] invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]
[Error] initializing argument 1 of 'void crypt(char)' [-fpermissive]***
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you for your answer. I changed to void crypt(char*); but i believe the while loop is correct with ||.

Comment: On second thought yes you were right on both accounts thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function prototype to

```
void crypt(char *);
```

As per OP's comment:

> right after "jhrujh" the program continues to print 7-8 more wired chars. any ideas?

Your logic in  `while` loop is wrong.

```
void crypt(char str[])
{
    int i=0;

    while (str[i]!='\0')
    {
        if (str[i]<=119) {str[i] = str[i] + 3;}
        else if (str[i]==120) {str[i]='a';}
        else if (str[i]==121) {str[i]='b';}
        else {str[i]='c';}
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. I changed it and it returns "jhrujh", which is the expected value, but right after "jhrujh" the program continues to print 7-8 more wired chars. any ideas?

Comment: Change your `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

you could try something like this instead

```
void crypt(char* str) // to conform with your prototype
{
   for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0' && i < 10; ++i)
   {    
     if (str[i]<=119) { str[i] = str[i] + 3; }
     else if (str[i]==120) { str[i]='a'; }
     else if (str[i]==121) { str[i]='b'; }
     else { str[i]='c'; }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. May I ask wheter there is a particular reason for your preference of the for loop over the while?

Comment: yes, i find it is more clear and straight-forward, the do loop needs to run one time before the while condition is checked so therefore it needs some take extra care.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace

```
int i=0;

if (str[0]!='\0')
{    
    do
    {
      ...
    }while ((i<=10)||(str[i]=='\0'));
}
```

(which contains a logical error in the `while` condition)

with

```
int i=0;

while (str[i]!='\0')
{    
    ...
}
```

because:

- the test for `i<=10` seems pointless and too restrictive to me and
- if you omit it, the `if` and `do..while` can better be expressed with a single `while` which checks at the start.